# is jsf and .net webforms alike?thye are stateful,render their own html tags

Tags: jsf, webforms

Is JSF (javaServer faces) same technology as .net WebForm? why is it still in use? .Net is not supporting WebForm anymore

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET and JSF are similar.

JSF is still in use because it's part of Java Enterprise Edition. For example PrimeFaces is one of the largest Component collection and has lot of active users.

Microsoft moved to MVC and later to .NET core. 
On the Java side you have Spring MVC as the equivalent.

Why is JSF still used: Because a component based model may have some advantages for enterprise business applications.

As always it depends and you have to choose the technology fits the requirements.

Btw. most frontends today are created using a SPA (Single Page Application) framework like Angular, React or Vue.